# True or false: Every transformation T: Cn --> Cn (n ≥ 2) has n distinct eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

True or false:

1) Every transformation T: Cn --> Cn (n ≥ 2) has n distinct eigenvectors

2) Every transformation T: Cn --> Cn (n ≥ 2) has at least 1 eigenvector

3) Every transformation T: Rn --> Rn (n ≥ 2) has at least 1 eigenvector

4) Every transformation T: Rn --> Rn (n ≥ 3) has at least 1 eigenvector

i believe 3 and 4 are both false because not all matrices are diagonalizable so you can't say that those statements are always true but i'm not completely confident

Comment: 3) and 4) are identical...

Comment: 1 is false as you said, because of nondiagonalizable matrices. You should know the answer to 2. For 3 and 4, are there any real matrices with no real eigenvalues? How does this depend on the dimension?